# Express js 4 and multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm writing a Node js application which handles multipart form data and so I'm using multer for the purpose.
The problem is that `req.body` is always undefined.

Here is my code:

```
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

//All environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || config.ports.HTTP_PORT);
app.set('views', config.folders.views);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Express 4 dependencies
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(multer({ dest: config.folders.uploads}))
app.use(cookieParser()); //Parser for cookie session
app.use(session({ secret: 'secret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize()); //Init passport
app.use(passport.session()); //Persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); //Flash messages

//Public folder
app.use(express.static(config.folders.public));

require('./auth')(passport); //Add auth methods to passport
require('./routes')(app, passport); //Add routes
```

---

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.body.test); //req.body always undefined

});
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT:

Now **req.body** is filled with data, but the req.files property is still undefined

Comment: not sure but maybe you need to also call app.use(express.bodyParser());

Comment: bodyParser() is not included in Express 4+

Comment: oh ok, didn't have any experience yet with express 4..

Comment: You can use it in express 4.

Comment: Show how are you sending your request. If you are submitting an HTML form, you have to explicitly set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>` tag to receive files.

Comment: thanks @mscdex i was using a simple html page to test the app and I foolishly forgot to add the encoding to the <form>

Answer (score 1):

add bodyParser with this code :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

Comment: It seems that this snippet has fixed the req.body, but req.files still remains undefined

Comment: No idea.I didn't use `multer`.

Comment: `bodyParser.*` does not handle files.

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms need to have the `enctype` attribute set appropriately in order for files to be sent. Example:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/foo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing your original code:
You have to install Multer  [Multer Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)
`npm i multer -S`

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const multer = require('multer'); // added, wasn't in your original code.

//All environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || config.ports.HTTP_PORT);
app.set('views', config.folders.views);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Express 4 dependencies
app.use(morgan('dev'));
// newly added
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(multer({ dest: config.folders.uploads}).single('file')) // added the single() method
app.use(cookieParser()); //Parser for cookie session
app.use(session({ secret: 'secret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize()); //Init passport
app.use(passport.session()); //Persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); //Flash messages

//Public folder
app.use(express.static(config.folders.public));

require('./auth')(passport); //Add auth methods to passport
require('./routes')(app, passport); //Add routes
```

Testing the code:

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.test); //req.body always undefined
    console.log(req.file); // added this, it should work fine now.
});
```